# How to unpack a tuple into arguments and pass to function which upon clicking a button changes a canvas color in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

i am a newbie to tkinter.
i am having difficulty figuring out an approach to unpack tuple into arguments and pass to function which would finally use it to change the color of canvas widget.
The code is actually a traffic light simulator in which tuple contains data which decides which light should be lit upon clicking of Next button.
Initially all 3 lights are in grey. on clicking Next, Red,grey,grey should be shown taking arguments from tuple where elements of inner tuples are assigned to red, yellow and green respectively. So for True, False, False, the result should be Red,grey,grey. And on subsequent clicks, the code should take inputs from tuple and display the lights. Any change done to the tuple should be accommodated by the code.

below is the code. Phases is the tuple here.

```
import tkinter as tk

phases = ((True,  False, False),
          (True,  True,  False),
          (False, False, True),
          (False, True,  False))

def Signal():
        '''<NEED HELP HERE>'''        
        Canvas.itemconfigure(C1,fill = "red")
        Canvas.itemconfigure(C2,fill = "red")
        Canvas.itemconfigure(C3,fill = "red")

TL = tk.Tk()
TL.minsize(80,550)
Canvas = tk.Canvas(TL,width=200, height=500, bg="#696969")
Canvas.grid()
C1 = Canvas.create_oval(38,160,160,30,outline="black",width=5,fill="#A9A9A9")
C2 = Canvas.create_oval(38,320,160,190,outline="black",width=5,fill="#A9A9A9")
C3 = Canvas.create_oval(38,480,160,350,outline="black",width=5,fill="#A9A9A9")
Next = tk.Button(TL, text = "Next", width = 8, command = Signal)
Next.grid()
##Next.bind("<Button-1>",Signal)
Quit = tk.Button(TL, text = "Quit", width = 8, command = TL.destroy)
Quit.grid()

TL.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can't see any attemp, please make sure, code you posts actually behaves as you claim.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your question reads like asking the solution for an assignment, so give it a good shot before you read below, which is actually not the best way to implement this. Ideally you want to make a class for your GUI and have your widgets and callback functions within. Nonetheless, here's one *nonoptimal* solution:

```
import tkinter as tk

phases = ((True, False, False),
          (True, True, False),
          (False, False, True),
          (False, True, False))

def Signal():
    Signal.cur_state = (Signal.cur_state + 1 ) % 4

    print(Signal.cur_state)

    Canvas.itemconfigure(C1, fill="red" if phases[Signal.cur_state][0] else '#A9A9A9')
    Canvas.itemconfigure(C2, fill="yellow" if phases[Signal.cur_state][1] else '#A9A9A9')
    Canvas.itemconfigure(C3, fill="green" if phases[Signal.cur_state][2] else '#A9A9A9')

Signal.cur_state = 0

TL = tk.Tk()
TL.minsize(80, 550)
Canvas = tk.Canvas(TL, width=200, height=500, bg="#696969")
Canvas.grid()
C1 = Canvas.create_oval(38, 160, 160, 30, outline="black", width=5, fill="#A9A9A9")
C2 = Canvas.create_oval(38, 320, 160, 190, outline="black", width=5, fill="#A9A9A9")
C3 = Canvas.create_oval(38, 480, 160, 350, outline="black", width=5, fill="#A9A9A9")
Next = tk.Button(TL, text="Next", width=8, command=Signal)
Next.grid()
##Next.bind("<Button-1>",Signal)
Quit = tk.Button(TL, text="Quit", width=8, command=TL.destroy)
Quit.grid()

TL.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank You, k-war. that was helpful. as i am new, i was not aware we could use if else inside a config command of widget after assigning a value.

Answer (score -1):

I use a global variable `count` that gets incremented when you press `Next`. I also create a list `colors` that is `["red", "black", "black"]` when `phase = (True, False, False)` for example.
You can try this :

```
import tkinter as tk

phases = ((True,  False, False),
          (True,  True,  False),
          (False, False, True),
          (False, True,  False))

def give_color(phase, light_number):
    colors_availables = ("red", "yellow", "green")
    return colors_availables[light_number-1] if phase[light_number-1] else "#A9A9A9"

global count
count = 0

def Signal():
    global count
    p = phases[count]
    Canvas.itemconfigure(C1,fill = give_color(p, 1))
    Canvas.itemconfigure(C2,fill = give_color(p, 2))
    Canvas.itemconfigure(C3,fill = give_color(p, 3))
    count += 1
    count = count%4

TL = tk.Tk()
TL.minsize(80,550)
Canvas = tk.Canvas(TL,width=200, height=500, bg="#696969")
Canvas.grid()
C1 = Canvas.create_oval(38,160,160,30,outline="black",width=5,fill="#A9A9A9")
C2 = Canvas.create_oval(38,320,160,190,outline="black",width=5,fill="#A9A9A9")
C3 = Canvas.create_oval(38,480,160,350,outline="black",width=5,fill="#A9A9A9")
Next = tk.Button(TL, text = "Next", width = 8, command = Signal)
Next.grid()
##Next.bind("<Button-1>",Signal)
Quit = tk.Button(TL, text = "Quit", width = 8, command = TL.destroy)
Quit.grid()

TL.mainloop()
```

Comment: You don't need to create the `colors` list in `give_color()`.  Just `return colors_availables[light_number-1] if phase[light_number-1] else "#A9A9A9"`.  Note that OP wants `grey` when phase is False.

Comment: Thank You, phoenixo and acw1668. that was helpful